# Set image uploader field using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, file-upload

I am trying to save user data while on later i give the option to user to see his unsaved work.I got all the data but image upload file is missing.I i am trying to save file field like this in DB :

```
$files = $_FILES;
$__fields['file'] = json_encode($files);
```

Then i save this field to DB.I tried to set the file field like this but no luck.

```
$files = json_decode($row['file']);
jQuery('#myimg'). val('<?php echo $files->name;?>');
```

what i am doing wrong ? I want that when customer see his unsaved data the file field is filled like he leaved it.Only file field is creating issue for me.Thanks

Comment: as you see in the answers below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a user unsaved a file means he doesn't uploaded to your server. the file is being in his local computer.
And Its not possible to take that it from php side. unless you upload the file.

Do one thing when the user select file then upload it to your server and keep it in a temporary place and then do your job.
hope this helps

Comment: great .I will accept your answer as i know how to upload.But know how to handle it.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As per the documentation, `$_FILES` is an associative array of items uploaded to the current script via the HTTP POST method. [See manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php)

**What you need to do;**

- Grab the contents of `$_FILES` on the initial HTTP POST.
- Validate the image
- Save the image to your server
- Store the location of the saved image in the database, to be read later
- **OR**
- Use a 3rd party API

  - http://api.imgur.com/

See http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

*(sorry for a w3schools link)*